# Markdown editing help page needs an update

Tags: feature-request, editing-help

The [Markdown Editing Help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#basic-links) shows this for the **Basic Links**:

> There are three ways to write links. Each is easier to read than the last:
>
> ```
> [Google](http://www.google.com/)Here's an inline link to .
> [Google][1]Here's a reference-style link to .
> [Yahoo!][yahoo]Here's a very readable link to .
>
>   [1]: http://www.google.com/
>   [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
> ```

Instead, it should look like

> ```
> Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).
> Here's a reference-style link to [Google][1].
> Here's a very readable link to [Yahoo!][yahoo].
>
>   [1]: http://www.google.com/
>   [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
> ```

Can this be updated?